# Trying to confirm XOR's mathematical property

Tags: xor

Is the following property true of the XOR operator ?

```
A XOR B = C
A XOR C = B
B XOR C = A
```

What would you call this property ?

This can be tested here.  Let me know if there are any cases where this property
doesn't hold true :

```
int main() {
    unsigned a = 128;
    unsigned b = 34;
    unsigned c = a ^ b;

    printf("a ^ c = %u\n", a ^ c);  // Gives you b (34)
    printf("b ^ c = %u\n", b ^ c);  // Gives you a (128)
}
```

Comment: Irrelevant C tag removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics))
"The XOR bitwise operation with a given value for one parameter is an involution."

Comment: Yes, Involution does seem to be the property.
`B XOR C = A` also appears to be true as well.
I just haven't seen it stated in this way in the wikis.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, the above can be written as

A XOR A XOR B

Here A XOR A is 0

So the result is 0 XOR C = C

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a name for such property. It implies from other properties of the *Exclusive Or* (see [Exclusive Or wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) for more details).

Here is the proof:

```
If a^b = c, then

    a^c = a^(a^b) = 
    <by associativity> 
    = (a^a)^b = 
    = 0^b = b
```